# How to get the keys of a ListElement?

Tags: qt, qml, key

how do I get in a `delegate` the keys of the `ListElement` that are in a `ListModel`, for example if I have the following:

```
ListModel {
    id: modeloDeLista
    ListElement{
        nombre: "Articulo 1"
        precio: 5000
        descripcion: "Esto es una descripción"
    }
    ListElement{
        nombre: "Articulo 2"
        precio: 8000
        descripcion: "Esto es una descripción"
    }
}

Item {
    width: parent.parent.width
    height: 16
    RowLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Item {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Text {
                text: key1 //<-----here would go the first key
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but in the delegate instead of being a `key1` one, I want to be something more automatic, and how would I know the amount of keys in a `ListElement`

Answer (score 2):

The delegate is just a prototype, you cannot get anything out of it. You can access properties of instances of the delegate.

The key of a list model element also serves as a role, if you want to get the associated value in a delegate, just use the key. So if your first key is `nombre` then simply use that. I mean... that's the whole idea of having those keys in the first place, so you can use them to refer to specific data properties.

List elements behave pretty much like regular JS objects, for example getting the number of keys is possible via `Object.keys(model.get(index)).length`. You can also iterate each object's keys and associated values.

But they come with some boilerplate stuff, so the number of keys will always be higher than the actual user explicit keys. So the number of keys is not really a relevant metric, and also its use suggests poor design, as QML views perform best when the "scheme" is static and known, and dynamic roles add a significant performance cost. The number of keys is not indicative because of duplications too:

```
ListElement {
  name: "sadas"
  value: 2
}
```

outputs:

```
qml: value 2
qml: name sadas
qml: name sadas
qml: objectNameChanged undefined
qml: __0 undefined
qml: __1 undefined
```

As you see, it contains duplications, signals and some other unrelated stuff.

Overall, your question hints that you don't know what you are doing, so if you share the goal you actually want to achieve it may be possible to give you better direction.

Comment: I'll try to specify when exactly that could be used. When I append ListModels element with such JSobject: `{ val: 1, arr: [0,1,2] }`, it appends correctly and I can see that `myModel.get(0).val = 1` and `myModel.get(0).arr` is a ListModel object with 3 elements. But how could I get their values since I didn't set any roles (or keys) for them?

Comment: Further investigation shows that appending `{ val: 1, arr: [0,1,2] }` as ListModels element turns out to be `{"val":1,"arr":[{},{},{}]}` as ListElement. So to have array filled, jsObject should be something like this: `{val:1, arr:[{x:0},{x:1},{x:2}]}`